Codepush installs a new update only when I reinstall the APK
I'm facing an issue with CodePush where I push a new update, but the application on my phone doesn't install it. Only after uninstalling and reinstalling the app does it download the update from CodePush and install it.
So, regardless of the update I push to CodePush, I have to uninstall and reinstall the application every time. Any insights into why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.
I pushed the update to CodePush and then opened the installed application on Android. It prompted me to install a new update. When I clicked "install," nothing happened, and the CodePush dashboard didn't show any updates to downloads or installs.
However, as soon as I uninstalled and reinstalled the application, a similar dialog appeared. This time, clicking "install" successfully downloaded and installed the update, and I could see the changes reflected in the app.

Does the deployment key in your app match the one you are using to push updates in CodePush? If they don't match, the app won't recognize the updates.

@Sohan The app key matches. Also, if the app key wasn't matching, there wouldn't have been any installs (installation happens once I uninstall and reinstall the app)

So basically, i posted the query on the issue section of react-native-code-push and i got to know that the version i was using (8.3.0) had a bug which caused this issue. Upgrading it to 8.3.1 resolved the issue.
Here's the reply by one of the developers:
https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/2732#issuecomment-2255170180

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
